# window.tableau is undefined in IE Edge

Tags: tableau-api, microsoft-edge

When embedding Tableau visuals into a page, we include Tableau JavaScript API. We tried different ways based on some of the support threads:

`<script src="https://xxx.xxx/javascripts/api/tableau-2.0.0.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://xxx.xxx/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://xxx.xxx/ie-sp-embed-javascripts/api/tableau-2.0.0.min.js"></script>`

Every other browser, including IE11, is able to load the script and window.tableau is defined and used to create a visual on the page. The Edge browser fetches the script, as can be seen in the Network tab of the developer tools, but window.tableau stays undefined.

Tableau Server Version: 10.5.23 (10500.20.0117.2214) 64-bit Windows

Looking for suggestions.

EDIT: the problem seems to stem from a security policy. Edge wouldn't load the script from inside of our VPN. However, everything works fine using Edge on outside computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to refer to the [sample example](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_basic_embed.htm) for Tableau JavaScript API from its official website.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Basic Embed</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initViz() {
            var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
                url = "http://public.tableau.com/views/RegionalSampleWorkbook/Storms",
                options = {
                    hideTabs: true,
                    onFirstInteractive: function () {
                        console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
                    }
                };

            var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
            // Create a viz object and embed it in the container div.
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initViz();">
    <div id="vizContainer" style="width:800px; height:700px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Output in MS Edge legacy browser (Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0):

[image]

Output in MS Edge Chromium browser (Microsoft Edge Version 83.0.478.13 (Official build) beta (64-bit)):

[image]

You can see that code is working fine and it is creating the visualization on the page.

I suggest you can try to run this example on your side and let us know about the results.

If the issue persists then please try to inform us which exact version of the MS Edge browser you are using for making this test? Please provide your sample code to reproduce the issue on our end. It can help us to understand the issue properly. We will try to check it and try to provide you further suggestions.

Comment: So the request for tableau API javascript is always received from cache no matter what I try: clearing cache, setting "always refresh from server" to on, changing file names, attaching a parameter like ?v=1 to the script url. Nothing helps. The body for request and response is always empty. That would explain why window.tableau is undefined. I need to force the Edge to get JS API from the server.

Comment: It seems that something was preventing Edge from loading the script in the first place. My laptop was connected to our internal VPN when that happened. Using Edge from outside worked as expected. Thank you.